# Can you bold a number variable in a string and express it the UI when placed in the html?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic3

I have the following situation:

Javascript:

```
var aNumber = 17;
var problem = "Is there a way to bold a number like this: "+aNumber+"?";
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>{{problem}}</ion-item>
```

I get:
Is there a way to bold a number like this: 17?

I want:
Is there a way to bold a number like this: **17**?

I've tried using `<b></b>` and `<strong></strong>` within the problem variable around the variable aNumber.

This looked like:

```
var problem = "Is there a way to bold a number like this: "<strong>+aNumber+</strong>"?";
```

No that didn't work either.

I also tried the following:

```
var aNumber = 17;
var problem = "Is there a way to bold a number like this: "
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>{{problem}}{{aNumber}}?</ion-item>
```

This answer only shows the problem variable:
Is there a way to bold a number like this:

Comment: You are missing a quote around the ending </strong> tag while setting var problem

Comment: `<ion-item>{{problem}}<b>{{aNumber}}</b>?</ion-item>`

Comment: Please tag the question with the templating library you use.

Comment: What is <ion-item>? Are you not looking for html javascript solution as your question shows under tags?

Comment: From `<ion-item>` it looks like the framework is _Ionic_ (which I don't know) but my first question would be, when using placeholders like `{{aNumber}}` is the output _sanitized_?  That would prevent putting tags in the variable from working.  It seems to me the right way to do this is `<ion-item>{{problem}} <strong>{{aNumber}}</strong>?</ion-item>` as ibrahim mahrir suggested.  Information such as `problem` and `aNumber` should not carry style with it — that is the job of the _presentation layer_ (the template).

Comment: @trincot Updated the templating library. Attempting to render the second variable is not working for some reason.

Comment: Thanks fellas. I got it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about `<ion-item>` but according to the tag mentioned in the problem, do it like this:

```js
var aNumber = 17;
var problem = "Is there a way to bold a number like this: <strong>" + aNumber + "</strong>?";

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = problem;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```